# Big-O Time Complexity of nested for loops

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

My gut tells me the time-complexity of the following code is simply O(n^2).  However, I'm not convinced, thinking it could possibly be O(n^3):

```
cin >> n;
sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n * n; j++)
        sum++;
```

Can anyone provide a distinction, and why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also [tag:runtime-analysis+loops]. And, important, [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-does-one-know-which-notation-of-time-complexity-analysis-to-use); $O(n^2)$ and $O(n^3)$ are not mutually exclusive, in fact $O(n^2) \subset O(n^3)$. You want to talk about $\Theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: What is the value of `sum` at the end of the code, as a function of $n$? If it is $s$ then the fifth line must have been run exactly $s$ times.

Comment: So, I ran the program and input 5, and the value of sum was 5^3 = 75.  Does this mean it is O(n^3) ?  Still not convinced.

Comment: Make sure that you understand the concept of running time. If a line is run $s$ times then the running time is at least $s$.

Comment: Thank you.  I mistyped in my previous comment, should be 125 instead of 75.